# Trailing Stop Loss - Get the alert of the exit filled price, to send to broker

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My broker does not have the same function as TV to send trailing stop order, essentially the activation price for the trailing.

So the orders get filled via the entry alert of my strategy, however, I would like to get the exit filled price of TV, for each current trade when the strategy usually send me the order to exit, in order to send this price as limit for my broker exit.

For now, the exit alert comes, my broker gets the exit signal as market order, but it's too different than the TV strategy, and usually I get out of the trade at loss, and 99% of the case the price goes back to the correct direction, and could fill this exit price.

All I've been able to do so far, is to get the last exit price, the one for the trade before the current trade I'm in. This is useless to me.
Here : `last_exit_price = strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(strategy.closedtrades - 1)`

Here the code:

```
trail_points_q = input.int(8,title= "Trail Points")
trailoff = input.int(1,title= "Trail Offset")
qty_dol = input.int(1,title= "QTY")
X_loss = input(110,title='Max Open Loss')



if buy_momentum2 or buy_momentum or div_bull_signal //and time>timestamp(2021, 01, 30) //and barstate.isconfirmed
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, qty=qty_dol,alert_message =long_enter_json,comment="Equity = $" + str.tostring(strategy.equity, "#.##"))
 
    
if sell_momentum2 or sell_momentum or div_bear_signal//and time>timestamp(2021, 01, 30) //and barstate.isconfirmed 
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, qty=qty_dol,alert_message =short_enter_json,comment="Equity = $" + str.tostring(strategy.equity, "#.##"))
   

last_exit_price = strategy.closedtrades.exit_price(strategy.closedtrades - 1)

//Exits
strategy.exit("Long Exit","Long",qty=qty_dol, loss = X_loss,trail_points = trail_points_q, trail_offset = trailoff,alert_message = exit_long_json,comment = str.tostring(last_exit_price))
strategy.exit("Short Exit","Short",qty=qty_dol,loss = X_loss,trail_points = trail_points_q, trail_offset = trailoff,alert_message = exit_short_json, comment =  str.tostring(last_exit_price))
```

I don't mind if the solution would be to create a new alert 1 second later, or a few milliseconds later, once the price in strategy tester of the last trade exit is mentioned, I need to send this info.

Edit : SOLVED

I was only trying with strategy formulas, and I could not wrap my head around the fact that

```
'{{close}}'
```

would work because I wanted the price at exit time, not at the close of the candle. Seems this way, even if it says close, pinescript send the actual price at the time of the alert.

Now it looks like :

```
last_exit_price = '{{close}}'
```

```
//Exits

strategy.exit("Long Exit","Long",qty=qty_dol, loss = X_loss,trail_points = trail_points_q, trail_offset = trailoff,alert_message = exit_long_json_limit + str.tostring(exit_price)) 
strategy.exit("Short Exit","Short",qty=qty_dol,loss = X_loss,trail_points = trail_points_q, trail_offset = trailoff,alert_message = exit_short_json_limit + str.tostring(exit_price))
```